# Azure devops rest api call : how to update the project capabilities (process and version control) of the project

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops-rest-api

I need to update the process of the azure devops project. I'm trying to update the process from basic to "basic-inherited-1"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

this is the payload

```
{
"capabilities":{
    "processTemplate": {
        "templateName": "basic-inherited-1",
        "templateTypeId": "539ee684-58a2-429a-bab2-b05ff7969ed0"
    }
}
```

}

But i'm getting the below error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKrsC.png)

Comment: Could you please try using PUT instead of PATCH ,Please let us know if it works. Also Check this https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/azure-devops-agents-update-api-patch-not-working-f/567978#T-N1000326

Comment: I tried but https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0 does not support PUT method

Comment: Thanks for the update , if you have followed the given doc. , You can ask the same [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/search?space=21) .